# Send a File between Vue views

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm writing a Vue app, and I don't know what is the best way to send a file from one View to another.
I have a view **FileUploadView** that allows you to choose a local file:

```js
function selectFile() {
  this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
}

function sendFile() {

  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  try {
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
    fileReader.onloadend = function() {
      console.log(fileReader.result); // This are the contents of a file
      this.$router.push({
        name: '/textInput',
        params: {
          inputText: fileReader.result
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<input type="file" ref="file" id="fileUpload" class="form-control-file .form-control-lg" @change="selectFile" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" /> Submit
</button>
```

When this view loads a file, I want to redirect user to **TextInputView** view and pass whole content of file.txt
**TextInputView** is a view that will look like this:

```js
function onTextChange() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputTextField").value;
  mock_send_data_to_server_and_return_results(inputText);
}

function mock_send_data_to_server_and_return_results(someText) {
  document.getElementById("outputTextAfterPostOnServer").innerText = someText.toUpperCase();

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">InputText</span>
        </div>
        <textarea id="inputTextField" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" onChange="onTextChange()"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4">Output text</h1>
          <p class="lead" id="outputTextAfterPostOnServer">Here the input text will be modified by backend, and returned.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The `textarea` element should contain the raw text of the file if it is passed, or be empty otherwise. This text will then be sent with a POST request to DJANGO server, analyzed (corrected) and returned in the same view to `#outputTextAfterPostOnServer` component.

This Question is not about sending a text from `TEXTAREA` to `#output...`.

I'm wondering what is the correct way to send a text from **FileUploadView** to **TextInputView**. right now I know, that I can pass it as a prop with VueRouter, but this limits my text to 2048 characters. How can I pass the whole text to TextInputView? 
Should I:

1. use vuex,
2. create TextInputView component inside FileUploadView and show it
   only v-if file has been selected?
3. should I send the file on the backend,
   retreive some kind of token from backend, change view passing the token
   as a parameter and use the token to retrieve the text?
4. some other method.

The project I'm working on is [here](https://github.com/huntekah/MastersThesis/tree/master/frontend).

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to send it to TextInputView? FileUploadView could easily have the textarea, show the file contents and post it to the django server? Also is there a reason TextInputView is just a normal javascript instead of vue?

Comment: TexInput is plain Javascript, because I wanted to show "minimal reproductible example", but hadn't have time to write this view in my app yet.
FileUploadView could have this text area - this is a great Idea. I was focused on reusing components and on simplicity - and didnt think of that soultion. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might be helpful for you. https://dev.to/alexmourer/sharing-data-between-components-invuejs-48me

If you run into any problems sharing data that way I like the Vuex option. They have different types of storage and it defaults to local storage which stores about 25MB.